# Why can't I select from a table named range without using backticks?

Tags: linux, mysql, syntax

I'm facing a problem with mysql. A query `select * from range;` works on mysql 5.0.22 but does not work mysql 5.1.61. but it works with backtick:
i.e.

```
select * from `range`;
```

Kindly help in this regard.

I want mysql 5.1.61 to execute the query without backtick (`)

Comment: Is "abc" the name of the table or is that just an example? The reason I ask is because the actual table name may be a reserved word in v5.1 but not in v5.0.

Comment: abc is an example. actual table name is range

Comment: I've check mysql reference Manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html word RANGE is reserved in my MySQL 5.1 but not in 5.0.

is there any possibility that i could execute query without backtick whatif the word is reserved.

Comment: Either use backticks or change the table name. Your choice.

Comment: John, to me your answer is a proper technical analysis, and deserves to be a real answer so it can be upvoted.  I'd upvote it.  Any chance you could post it?

Answer (score 3):

range is a reserved word in 5.1

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

So if you use it, you need to use the back ticks in order to tell mysql that you aren't using the reserved word. range wasn't in 5.0

Comment: Yes i read reference manual and change mysql table name instead of range to someother, Thanks Jhon for the hint.